# Calling private functions nested in a var Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to rewrite a file to incorporate public and private vars. I am trying to do something like so:

```
var PrivateFunc = (function() {

  //Private Functions
  var _iAmPrivate = function(param, args){
    //code
  }

  var _soAmI = function(param){
    //code
  }

  return PrivateFunc;
})();

var PubObj = {
  someVar: 1,
  getPrivFunc: PrivateFunc,

  publicFunc: function(param){
    //This doesnt work
    this.getPrivFunc._iAmPrivate(someVar, param);
    //This doesn't either
    getPrivFunc._soAmI(param);
  }

};
```

I am a "`getPrivFunc` is undefined" error. I thought that moving `getPrivFunc` outside of `PubObj` could work, but i ran into the same issue. Calling `PrivateFunc` give errors as well. I feel like it is a silly error, I am just not seeing it.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: *"I am a "getPrivFunc is undefined" error."* That's because `PrivateFunc` is `undefined`. What you actually do is assigning the variable to itself (`return PrivateFunc;`). It's the same as `var foo = foo;`. But since `foo` (`PrivateFunc`) was never assigned a different value, its value will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything declared with a `var` is going to be inaccessible outside the function it's declared in. You could do something like the following, instead. The important thing to keep in mind is that *where* your `var`s occur defines the scope of their declaration.

```
var PubObj;
(function() {
  PubObj = {
    someVar: 1,

    publicFunc: function(param) {
      _iAmPrivate(this.someVar, param);
      _soAmI(param);
    }
  };

  //Inner Functions
  var _iAmPrivate = function(param, args) {
    //code
  };

  var _soAmI = function(param) {
    //code
  };
})();
```

Comment: That makes sense. I could see how that could work. I was guessing that keeping everything wrapped in `PubObj` would work too? This is a rewrite of an existing file, and `PubObj` is called many times throughout the program.

Or would it be something like `var p = PubObj; p.publicFunc(param);`?

Comment: Just updated the sample; does that fit with what you're asking? The way it's defined now, `PubObj` is accessible both from within the "private" functions and in the global scope of the file.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your PrivateFunc wasn't returning anything, because you're using OOP concepts without proper implementation. If we create a function that sets a property on `this` for each of your private functions, you can create an instance of it with the `new` keyword.

```
var PrivateFunc = new function() {
  this._iAmPrivate = function(param, args) {
    console.log('PrivateFunc._iAmPrivate called with', param, args);
  }

  this._soAmI = function(param) {
    console.log('PrivateFunc._soAmI called with', param);
  }
}();
```

We can then access PrivateFunc from inside of your PubObj.

```
var PubObj = {
  someVar: 1,
  getPrivFunc: PrivateFunc,

  publicFunc: function(param) {
    this.getPrivFunc._iAmPrivate(this.someVar, param);
    this.getPrivFunc._soAmI(param);
  }
};
```

When we call PubObj.publicFunc('test'), we get:

```
PubObj.publicFunc('test')
> PrivateFunc._iAmPrivate called with 1 test
> PrivateFunc._soAmI called with test
```